# How to disable the shield in shielded Cat8 ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, cable

I recently installed shielded Cat 8 ethernet cable in my house during unrelated renovations due to water damage that required opening up the walls. The electrician also installed shielded RJ45 Cat 8 termination plugs at both ends of the cable. At the time I was not at all familiar with shielded ethernet cable.

I have tried using the new Cat 8 cable to connect my Wi-Fi access point to my $30 network switch from Amazon but it's not working. After reading about ethernet cables online, I now suspect this is because the ethernet cable is not grounded as required.

I'm interested in using the installed ethernet cable from my network switch to my Wi-Fi access point and do not want to deal with network patches and grounding of both ends, etc. I would also love to avoid having to replace this shielded cable that's now buried in the walls with unshielded cable.

Is it possible to disable/ disconnect the shield of the shielded Cat 8 cable without replacing it? I found a comment on an audiophile forum that said: "It takes less than a minute to cover the sides of one of the plugs with a piece of tape, and the shield is unconnected."

I do not understand what that means or whether something like this could work. I would appreciate any advice on whether this is doable and, if so, how to describe what I'm trying to do to an electrician so that I can get my buried ethernet cable to work.

Comment: “ I have tried using the new Cat 8 cable to connect my Wi-Fi access point to my $30 network switch from Amazon but it's not working. After reading about ethernet cables online, I now suspect this is because the ethernet cable is not grounded as required.” Classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think that is the issue? I am pretty confident it is because you have your modem on one side of the switch, router on the other and your switch right in the middle. Do not do that. (1/2)

Comment: What you need to do is connect the modem directly to the router. And the connect the router to the switch. That is the way it works. Any problems you are having has nothing to do with shielding but has to do with network layout. Always connect the modem directly to router and then any switch to the router and all will be fine. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you and sorry I wasn't clearer, I have already done that. The modem is directly connected to the router and the router is directly connected to the switch. And when I connect the Wi-Fi access point to the switch using a non-shielded ethernet cable it works just fine.

Comment: So the the access point doesn’t work at cat with shielded Cat8?

Comment: Can you show a photo of the RJ45 connectors at both ends of the cable (whether plugs or sockets)? Also, how long is the cable, and does it actually go parallel to mains lines anywhere?

Comment: "*it's not working*" - That's a poor description of the problem. What doesn't work? Is there any Ethernet connection? Or is there interference with the WiFi?

Comment: Use a network cable tester and test that the cable has not been damaged in the process. For it to work either as a lower speed cat6, it should at least have pins 1 to 8 work correctly. If you get the colors wrong, but all colors are connected to the same pins on both ends, it should still work as a cat3 cable with a max of 100mbps.

Answer (score 1):

A note to others experiencing issues like this: Check and confirm the wires are correctly terminated.

Shielding on a cable does not block traffic on the cable. Wires out of order at the ends of the cable does block traffic on the cable.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was indeed the shield of the cable, and my electrician solved it. The Cat8 cable now works.

I do not own a network tester yet (the $9 Amazon one is arriving tomorrow, thank you for the suggestion), so what I mean by "it works" is that when I connect the cable to the Wi-Fi access point, the AP now works perfectly and extends my network.

Indeed, the access point that previously would not work at all now attains a greater speed after 30ft of originally-shielded-but-now-unshielded Cat8 cable (668mbps with 18ms latency) than the Xfinity X1 Wi-Fi router that it is connected to (641mbps with 18ms latency). Likely measurement error but you get the picture, indistinguishable performance. Both tests on iPhone located one foot away from the Wi-Fi antenna.

I am posting the solution here in case this is useful for others folks who inadvertently make the same mistake and needlessly install shielded cable: My electrician solved it by wrapping the "copper sticker" around the metal jacket. Then, at the jack, he wired it so every individual wire is in its correct spot that’s designated on the jack.

Comment: That last line makes it sound like he hadn't got the pinout right the first time, so it was that, and not the shield, that was the problem.

Comment: “Then, at the jack, he wired it so every individual wire is in its correct spot that’s designated on the jack.” What does that mean? It sounds like it was never a shielding problem but instead bad wiring was corrected.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, perhaps the shielding was irrelevant. I will try to find out.

Comment: Yes, the shielding is irrelevant. Did the electrician charge you for their further work that included the "copper sticker" and correcting the end wiring? If so, they are cheating you. They wired the cables incorrectly to begin with and that was the only issue you were dealing with.